# jq how to extract field only if exists for yt-dlp json dump

Tags: json, jq, dump, yt-dlp

When i run the following:

> yt-dlp --dump-json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nochapters | jq -cr '{ Date: .upload_date |
> (.[0:4] + "-" + .[4:6] + "-" + .[6:8]), ID: .id, Title: .fulltitle,
> Chaps: .chapters[] | {title} |  join(", ") }'

it gives me an error:

> jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over null (null)

How can extract the chapters from those videos that really have chapters? (because I think it gets stuck when no chapters are found).

Edit:

Input is like (in this example chapters exists):

> {   "id": "pvkTC2xIbeY",   "title": "How to Add Chapters
> to YouTube Videos | Chapters Explained",   "formats": [
> {
> "format_id": "sb2",
> "format_note": "storyboard",
> ...
> "comment_count": 2600,   "chapters": [
> {
> "start_time": 0,
> "title": "Intro",
> "end_time": 10
> },
> {
> "start_time": 10,
> "title": "YouTube Chapters",
> "end_time": 45
> },... } }

Output like:

> {"Date":"2020-06-17","ID":"pvkTC2xIbeY","Title":"How to Add Chapters
> to YouTube Videos | Chapters Explained","Chaps":"Intro, YouTube
> Chapters, What are YouTube chapters?, How to add chapter markers?,
> When are changes updated?, How to disable chapters?, Are chapters
> available in my country?"}

Comment: Please show input and desired output

Comment: What is the output of `yt-dlp --dump-json`? What is the value of `chapters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.chapters` is not present, it evaluates to `null`, and `.chapters[]` will fail with the error `Cannot iterate over null (null)`.

Depending on what you want as result value in this case, you could wrap the critical part in parentheses, use the error suppression operator `?` to silence the error, and provide an alternative with the alternative operator `//`, e.g. `(…)? // null`.

Note: `.chapters[] | {title} | has("title") | join(", ")` doesn't make sense even if there are chapters, as `has` returns a boolean. Do you want to concatenate the chapter titles, separated by commas, into a long string? Use `.chapters | map(.title?) | join(", ")` instead.

```bash
jq -c '{
  Date: .upload_date | (.[0:4] + "-" + .[4:6] + "-" + .[6:8]),
  ID: .id,
  Title: .fulltitle,
  Chaps: ((.chapters | map(.title) | join(", "))? // null)
}'
```

Comment: It works :) (I removed | has("title"), it was a copy paste error. Sorry for that.)